# A puzzle of d's (What is the full name of the artist shop?)

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

**As it says in the title, what is the full name of the artist shop? Explain why.**

---

```
       I have a pet, erroneously taken for another animal. 
       Mahal Taj, oh, not the right order. 
       Awesome jam, especially the last part.   x2
       He's very unprofessional, I think they should ban Dr Ewan. 
       I used to spell uphill as uphil - I pretty confidently thought it was correct
       U'll get it tho, master it and it's all yours. 
       I finally made him submit on the mat - the winner was me! 
       MJ, u'd astonish anyone of these youngsters today, the way you were dunking back in the days was on a whole other level!      x2
       Yes, I'm on my way!  
       I just visited a newly opened animal artist shop, it had a weird name, "Club ??? ???? ???". I think it kinda translates into "a whole artist shop of cats". 
                              

                 Letter counts (up to you to match them to each line above):

                         (4),(5),(5),(5),(5),(6),(6),(6),(7),(11)
```

Comment: **Note:** This is an enigmatic-puzzle and doesn't rely on you knowing the answers to some obscure crossword-clues.  And although the knowledge required is not trivial, it's still familiar for most people in here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a puzzle on

> twelve disciples of Jesus, as every line contains the name of a disciple.
>  The letter counts corresponds to the length of name that is found in each line.

> I have a **pet, er**roneously taken for another animal. (Peter)

> Mahal Ta**j, oh, n**ot the right order. (John)

> Awesome **jam, es**pecially the last part.   x2 (James)

> He's very unprofessional, I think they should b**an Dr Ew**an. (Andrew)

> I used to spell uphill as u**phil - I p**retty confidently thought it was correct (Philip)

> U'll get it **tho, mas**ter it and it's all yours. (Thomas)

> I finally made him submit on the **mat - the w**inner was me! (Matthew)

> M**J, u'd as**tonish anyone of these youngsters today, the way you were dunking back in the days was on a whole other level!      x2 (Judas)

> Ye**s, I'm on** my way! (Simon)

> I just visited a newly opened animal artist shop, it had a weird name, "Club ??? ???? ???". I think it kinda translates into "a whole artist shop of cats".
>  Here, the name clearly corresponds to Bartholomew.

So, for the final line, it should read

> I just visited a newly opened animal artist shop, it had a weird name, "Club Art Holo Mew".

Comment: That's the answer. Nice job!

Comment: I wish the other two disciples of Jesus were also included in the question body.